# What does "neato burrito" mean?

Tags: etymology, slang

What does "neato burrito" mean?
Where is it coming from and when is the right time to use it?

Comment: Hello, and welcome! While this is an interesting question, it probably won't get answers here, as "burrito" is not English, and "neato" is not in the dictionary.

Comment: My opinion: 'neato' is a US slang variation of 'neat' used to mean admirable, good, 'cool', etc; a burrito is a Mexican food dish made of a thin flatbread wrapped around minced meat, rice, etc. 'Neato burrito' could be a [rhyming catch-phrase](https://www.reddit.com/r/AskReddit/comments/61mkn6/whats_your_favorite_rhyming_descriptor_like_neato/) expression (like 'easy-peasy', 'even-steven', 'whacko tobacco' etc) meaning 'good'. 'Neato Burrito' is also the name of a chain of Mexican restaurants.

Comment: See https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask for more detail. Cheers, and again, welcome!

Comment: @Decapitaded soul Ok, I'll be glad to recant, but the down-vote wasn't mine! I'll even give my +1 for a question about etymology.

Comment: @Conrado *burrito* is in the English dictionary on my bookshelf, so it's not clear to me why you think it's not an English word.  I can't find *neato* in a printed dictionary, though it is in both Wiktionary and dictionary.com, but from my perspective that seems to be a failing of my dictionary collection or or the dictionaries themselves.  The word has been in use for at least 50 years.

Comment: @Conrado sorry.  I posted that without having read your recantation.  I did want to point out, however, that the two points you made are somewhat inconsistent in their reasoning (and also to express my surprise that "neato" is not in any of my printed dictionaries).  Had I read your recantation, I would have worded my comment differently.

Comment: Context would be needed to reliably interpret the meaning.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

'Neato burrito' is a synonym of *[neato](https://www.lexico.com/definition/neato)*, which is an American slang word meaning *excellent, desirable, wonderful, fantastic* etc. 'Neato' dates back to the [1950s](https://www.lexico.com/definition/neato) and was formed by appending the suffix [*-o*](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/558969/365490) to the word *neat*. The word *burrito* was added to *neato* for rhyming.

[Reduplication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reduplication) is a process in which a word or part of it is repeated exactly or with slight modifications. *Neato burrito* reflects a special type of reduplication called **Rhyming reduplication**. A rhyming reduplication is one in which the duplicated element rhymes with the original element in the phrase which is indeed the case in *neato burrito*:

- neato → /ˈn**iːtəʊ**/
- burrito → /bʊˈr**iːtəʊ**/

A syllable consists of two main parts; *onset* and *rhyme*:

- **onset:** it refers to the consonant(s) before the nucleus (usually a vowel)
- **rhyme:** it consists of a nucleus (mostly a vowel) and an optional coda (consonants after the nucleus). It is the part of the syllable *used in most poetic rhymes*

Other examples of *rhyming reduplication* are *nitty gritty, namby pamby, itsy bitsy, fuzzy wuzzy, mumbo jumbo, razzle dazzle, superduper* etc. (More examples at: [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/weird-rhyming-words), [Poetry4Kids](https://www.poetry4kids.com/news/list-of-rhyming-phrases/), [WriteAtHome Blog](http://blog.writeathome.com/index.php/2013/05/reduplication/).)

Comment: These rhyming catch-phrases are very common. I just thought of "okey-dokey". A thin male person or a thin thing  might be a 'slim jim'; a fool could be a 'silly billy'; in the 1970s we expressed refusal with 'no way, José!'.

Comment: Way to go, Joe! I just made that up, then found out that it actually exists!

Comment: The chorus of '50 Ways to Leave Your Lover' by Paul Simon has: slip out the back, Jack, make a new plan, Stan, you don't need to be coy, Roy, hop on the bus, Gus, just drop off the key, Lee. A British woman who is fond of profane language might be called [a] 'sweary Mary'.

Comment: They get extended:  Good night, sleep tight, don't let the bedbugs bite (very common in the UK),