# Why do so many prefixes end with -o? (Visio, linguo)

Tags: etymology, prefixes, greek, affixes

At first I was wondering about “Deleuzoguattarian” but then I saw the Wiktionary list: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Category:English_prefixes which is quite striking.

The answers in [Origin of colloquializing suffix -o](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/558965/origin-of-colloquializing-suffix-o) point to a colloquial explanation, but I’m wondering if there’s possibly Greek origin as well, or maybe just phonetic ease. Anyone have intuitions?

Comment: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-o-#Interfix suggests where it's commonest. The wide use with Latin and Greek could suggest a link to -os/-us but that's not always the starting point. I doubt there's a single general explanation.

Comment: I think answers about "combining vowels" would be appropriate. https://www-s3-live.kent.edu/s3fs-root/s3fs-public/file/Section-I-Introduction.pdf#:~:text=When%20you%20take%20a%20word,not%20included%20in%20this%20rule.