# How did "combo" arise as an abbreviation for "combination"?

Tags: etymology, slang, abbreviations

I am interested in the shortening of "combination" to "combo." I understand the etymology of "combination," and it's clear to me how "comb-" would be used taken for the shorthand.

I see several sources indicate that it was first used with jazz/musical groups in the 1920s ([Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/combo), [Etymonline](https://www.etymonline.com/word/combo)).

Where does the "-o" ending come from? Is there a common convention or parallel word that the -o ending could have arisen from? Or is it something arbitrary that caught on?

Comment: The Marx Brothers popularised the -o modification. From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marx_Brothers#Origin_of_the_stage_names):  The stage names of the brothers (except Zeppo) were coined by monologist Art Fisher during a poker game in Galesburg, Illinois, based both on the brothers' personalities and Gus Mager's 'Sherlocko the Monk', a popular comic strip of the day that first appeared in 1910 and that included a supporting character named "Groucho". As Fisher dealt each brother a card, he addressed them, for the very first time, by the names they kept for the rest of their ...

Comment: lives. And 'An earlier version of Sherlocko, entitled Knocko the Monk spawned a fad of nicknames ending in O, which prompted a vaudeville monologist named Art Fisher, while playing poker with four brothers who performed together, to give them all such names.' Again, [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hawkshaw_the_Detective#Sherlocko). This may have influenced the similar whimsical mangling of common nouns.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I think kiddo, boyo, bucko, and wino kind of belie that hypothesis as an origin point. Also, using -o in an abbreviation is not the same as the -o suffix used in those nicknames or later words like weirdo or cheapo which aren't truncated.

Comment: @GArthurBrown Yes, _bucko_ and _kiddo_ are apparently late 19th century. Etymon suggests that the later _wino_ was formed by mimicry, so there's no reason why these common nouns couldn't have informed the style of the comic names. And the very famous examples (_Groucho, Harpo_ etc) then could return the favour. I don't think people coming up with such -o forms are very bothered about patternings other than the obvious. -O is a fun ending. Green grow the rushes-O.

Comment: Solo, duo, trio... combo.

Comment: ... which certainly sounds better than _combet_.

Comment: Combi is also an abbreviation for combination, as in combi boiler and combi van. Probably not much logic involved.

Comment: And perhaps influenced by the names of Latin-American dances and musical instruments: tango, mambo, bolero, tondero, bongo, bombo, apito, surdo, pandeiro, güiro, cuatro, agogo, er... Latino, um... Puerto Rico...

Comment: I was about to type up the OED entry for *-o* suffixing, but fortunately someone has already [done that](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/558965/origin-of-colloquializing-suffix-o).